# continuous map on a bounded set is proper (inverse image of compact set is compact)?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry

Let $U \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ be an open unit ball and $F : U \to \mathbb{R}^n$ be continuous and also nonzero Jacobian determinant at all points on $U$. I was wondering if it then follows that $F: U \to F(U)$ is proper...

Without the nonzero determinant assumption one can easily find a counterexample, for example take $F = 0$. However with the additional nonzero determinant assumption I wasn't too sure. Any comments are appreciated!

ps a separate but related question I want to ask is if we replace $U$ with any closed and bounded subset, then is continuity alone enough for $F$ to be proper?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is false, consider the map $f: \mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$ defined by $e^x(\cos y,\sin y)$, it's Jacobian is $e^{2x}$, so it has
non-zero determinant for every point. Consider the point $p= (1,0)$, then $f^{-1}(p)= \{(0,2\pi n) \ | \ n \in \mathbb{Z}\}$. Clearly $f^{-1}(p)$ is infinite and discrete, therefore not compact. Now chose any diffeomorphism $\psi: U \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$ between $\mathbb{R}^2$ and an open unit ball $U$, thus $f \circ \psi : U \rightarrow f(U) $ satisfies all condition you require but it is not proper, since $(f \circ \psi)^{-1} (p) = \psi^{-1}(f^{-1}(p))$ is not compact.

If you require $U$ to be closed and bounded it would be compact, since the pre-image of closed sets is closed and closed subsets of compact  spaces is compact the result follows. Note that this holds because any subspace of $\mathbb{R}^n$ has that property that every compact subset is closed (because they are hausdorff).